# Integrating a compound expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have an integral of the form

```
I[r]=∫(arExp[-r]-brSin[k(r-d)]Exp[-r])BesselJ[0,kr]dr
```

where `Besse1J[0,kr]` is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and `a`, `b`, `k` and `d` are constants. We are integrating from `0` to `R`.
The problem is I couldn't get an answer using *Mathematica*. Is there something I could do and solve the integral ?

Comment: `is there something I could do and solve the integral` you can try numerical integration. You would need to assign numerical value for the symbols. btw, you have typos in there. `BesselJ` is written as `Besse1J`. There is no digit `1` in the name, it is the letter `l`. Here is the code: `expr = (a r Exp[-r] - b r Sin[k (r - d)] Exp[-r]) BesselJ[0, k r];`, with numerical integration it works: `NIntegrate[expr /. {k -> 1, a -> 1, d -> 2, b -> 3}, {r, 0, 10}]` gives 1.49

Comment: Sorry for the problem of BesselJ..But I want to get a function about R(upper limit of integral)..Can I get a approximate one by some commands?

Comment: M can't find analytical antiderivative. you can try different upper limits, build table of data, and try to do an interpolation function of the result.

Comment: AHA...YES..I can try this way..Thank U very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding comment:

M can't find analytical antiderivative. you can try different upper limits, build table of data, and try to do an interpolation function of the result, something like:

```
expr = (a r Exp[-r] - b r Sin[k (r - d)] Exp[-r]) BesselJ[0, k r];
expr = expr /. {k -> 1, a -> 1, d -> 2, b -> 3};
data = Table[{R0, NIntegrate[expr, {r, 0, R0}]}, {R0, 0, 10, .1}];
ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"R", "f(R)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

i just a bit improove the solution of @Nasser

```
expr[r_] := (a r Exp[-r] - b r Sin[k (r - d)] Exp[-r]) BesselJ[0, 
k r] /. {k -> 1, a -> 1, d -> 2, b -> 3};

f[R_] := f[R] = NIntegrate[expr[r0], {r0, 0, R}]

Plot[f[r], {r, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can I change this curve to a two dimensional one by polar coordinates? And the center should be the (0,0)..Then get the DensityPlot of the 2D data..as a circle or rings..

Comment: the curve directed by f[r] in polar coordinates you can see with PolarPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 10}]

Comment: OK.Thank U so much